# How to properly implement a Android Cursor that gets data from an HTTP Server?

Tags: android, cursor

I have a server that returns data in JSON format (I author the server code).

I am planning to extend the abstract AbstractWindowedCursor and load remote data into this window. Is this the right way to do?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be to use a `AsyncTask` to open a connection to your server.
Take a look at the [example code from Google](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloWorld#2-connecting-your-android-app-to-the-backend) on how to do this.
Better implementation would involve using [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) or some other library like [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). However, the example above from Google will give you a good idea of what goes on under the hood and is a good place to start.

Is there a reason you want to use the `AbstractWindowedCursor`? I've never seen it used for api calls, it's really more for querying the database.

Comment: I have implemented the WindowedCursor myself. The steps are:
1. Connect to the server and retrieve data
2. Fill the data into the CursorWindow object

I also override getCount and getColumnNames. I also check whether data has been fetched from server in order not to make requests to server again and again.